# Not able to locate the object using Selenium

Tags: javascript, xpath, selenium

Hi I have the below html code, I am not able to identify the input id button while Using Selenium (through Java). It is saying unable to locate the element. Could you please help me out?

I tried using xpath and cssselector method but it is of no use. Do i need to learn Javascript executor class for it?
What are the various ways...

Kindly help me out

```
<span class="filed">
<input id="SubmitButton" type="submit" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("SubmitButton", "", true, "Validation", "", false, false))" value="SubmitButtonLabel" name="SubmitButton"/>
</span>
```

Comment: what `xpath` and `css selector` you used,share please.

Comment: Another thing to check is if the input is contained within a frame or iframe.  If it is, you'll need to use Driver.SwitchTo.Frame("frameIdentifier") and then you should be able to access the element.

Comment: It might be helpful to post all the parent elements of SubmitButton so that we can see all the elements containing it. It might be something as simple as an element that is hidden, or, as Richard suggested, your element may be in another frame.

Comment: Could be that the element hasn't loaded in the DOM yet. Try waiting for `visibilityOFElement` (see my answer)

Comment: Is the site live on the web? Can you share the url?

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the element hasn't loaded in the DOM yet. Try waiting for expected conditions.

```
Wait<WebDriver> wait= new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver).withTimeout(15L, TimeUnit.SECONDS).pollingEvery(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

WebElement submitButton= wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("SubmitButton")));
```

Comment: @Babai - I have used driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='SubmitButton']") and driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input#SubmitButton")

Comment: Thanks... let me try this.. and I will let you... I think is for sure.. I have learnt something new.. :D

Comment: Do i need to use javascript or action class is the solution for this ?